# What is electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

In quantum mechanics, we easily talk about some "particles" or "somethings" like electron and photon. Besides, in classical mechanics we talk about particles that have mass. As we know, one can formulate axiomatically the meaning of a particle in Newtonian mechanics. Is there any similiar approach to understand "what is electron" in quantum mechanics? Some people say the electron is something that has mass and charge, and we can talk about its wave function. Moreover, every "atoms" have natural number of electron. I guess I cannot understand what is electron.

Comment: begin with [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom#Subatomic_particles) , read the entire page and then come back to ask for a consistent question

Comment: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-field-theory/#Wigner http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191010/rest-mass-and-wigners-classification

Comment: @igael i think my question is consistent

Comment: atom is composite while electron is a fundamental particle/wave. What are you comparing ? or add some details to the question if it is consistent ...

Comment: Lots of things in physics can't be observed directly. But we can see their effects and postulate a particle or wave or field to explain our experimental results. So long as our observations are consistent with our model (of particles and waves and fields) we believe those things are real. Electrons were first observed in experiments on [cathode rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray).

Comment: There is no comprehensive answer to this question to this day, in my opinion. I want to warn you though, that wavefunction does not describe a 'particle', for example the wavefunction of a 'free' particle describes an infinite wave filling the whole space. On the other hand wave packet does not describe a 'particle' either since it spreads very quickly

Comment: @igael maybe it is easy for you to understand what is electron but it doesn't work for me. I cannot understand what is atom. I think they are just arised from our intuition.

Comment: An electron is an observed particle of nature. In the currently tested physical theories that we have, an electron has no internal structure. So it's just a particle that obey's the Schrödinger's equation, i.e., it follows quantum superposition principle. There has to at some point come a limit where we cannot anymore ask 'what's that made up of'; the electron can be considered that point.

Comment: @Sidd i didnt ask what electron is made of! Absolutely it was not my question! I asked what does it MEAN when we talk about electron? You used some words their definitions aren't clear. For instance, you wrote: "So it's just a particle ..." What is particle? That was exactly my question.

Comment: @K.N.O. A particle is an entity that we observe. We know it's properties, and how it behaves in different circumstances. We know that when observed, we 'see' it in a particular position. That's about it. I do not think there's any particular way of axiomatizing a particle in NM that won't be applicable in QM, for questions of this sort.

Comment: @Sidd we dont observe elemntary particles. We just observe their effects. So what does it mean when we say this sentence "electron's mass is 0.51 MeV/c2". Is it a postulate? Because in laboratory, we cannot see measure its mass directly. We SAY its mass is blah blah

Comment: @K.N.O. We define things like the mass of an entity based on it's reaction to forces. Relativity itself shows that the old way of saying 'mass is the amount of matter in an object' is not appropriate. So it's the properties that we study that reveal the nature of an object. Again, 'mass' is a 'defined' property of an entity.

Comment: @Sidd nice. So I think in particle physics we have almost over 20 postulates! Because we have more than 10 elementary particles in Standard model and all of them have charge and mass. As you said, we postulate their masses and charges. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @K.N.O. No; I meant that we postulate that mass is a property such that it manifest itself as a consequence for the entity. Let's take this example: Let's say we figure out an equation that describes the motion of electrons, but it has this arbitrary constant that has to be experimentally measured. Now, this new variable will be a 'property' of the entity. Why? Because changing it changes the behavior of electrons. The whole idea is that a property isn't always something tangible. It's a more of a descriptive tool; for example, take spin.

Comment: @Sidd the value of properties define the particle. Yea?

Comment: @K.N.O.Yes, because that is the only way we know about them. For example, the Higgs particle was confirmed by how it moved around in magnetic and electric fields, and how it decayed. But if there are two types of Higgs particles, with exactly the same properties (each and every single measurable property), then they will be the same thing to us, because they have the exact same measurable properties. It is like using an arbitrary phase factor in quantum mechanical solutions. In some situations, we cannot measure the phase difference - it manifests only as a mathematical property.

Comment: @Sidd so why physicists believe they can formulate the world only using finite elementary particles? It seems unreasonable because one can imagine infinite possibilities for masses, charges, and other properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33655/discussion-between-sidd-and-k-n-o).

Answer (score 3):

One has to keep firmly in mind that physics is about experimental observations and mathematical models that not only fit current observations but also have accurate predictive power for future setups.

Before the end of the 19th century "particles" meant  objects characterized with a mass that followed classical mechanics ( Newtonian physics), and  radiation which followed Maxwell's equations. It is instructive to read the histories of how  atoms and electrons and photons were first observed. The [electron in particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#Discovery) has a long experimental story.

> In 1896, the British physicist J. J. Thomson, with his colleagues John S. Townsend and H. A. Wilson,[13] performed experiments indicating that cathode rays really were unique particles, rather than waves, atoms or molecules as was believed earlier.[2](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html) Thomson made good estimates of both the charge e and the mass m, finding that cathode ray particles, which he called "corpuscles," had perhaps one thousandth of the mass of the least massive ion known: hydrogen

Since then a "particle" tag has been following the electron , up to the standard model physics [table of elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg).

In a simplistic manner an electron is a particle that hits the cathode ray tube television surface and gives the images . It has mass, it hits a point at (x,y) on the screen and fits the form of a classical particle.

Nevertheless it is not confined to classical particle characteristics. At the microscopic scale it obeys the laws of quantum mechanics, not classical mechanics. This means that in specific experiments, as the [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles),  even though one electron at a time is used, an interference pattern may appear in the accumulation of hits on a screen, indicative of the solutions of the [quantum mechanical wave equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html), which predicts the outcome of such experiments as probability distributions. The last link gives the "axiomatic" assumptions of quantum mechanics, which successfully predict experimental results. It is postulate number 1 that assumes particles exist ( as do newtonian physics)

Using the Schrodinger equation and an electron in the electric field of a proton one gets the [Hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html) wave function, and the solutions for transitions from the energy levels fit the spectra measured. This validates the quantum mechanical postulates and again the electron's  behavior has sine and cosine shapes indicating a wave nature for the probability of finding one around hydrogen. A recent experiment [has recorded this](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/may/23/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom).

So an electron is a particle having the attributes given in the table of particles of the standard model and its behavior is governed by quantum mechanical equations which give probabilities for measurements of position and energy, and not classical trajectories.

Comment: No modern axiomatic of quantum mechanics begins with the existence of particles. Not even classical mechanics begins with that.

Comment: @CuriousOne We shall not agree in this. Axioms are a part of mathematics. Postulates are the statements that connect mathematics with physical measurements. An axiomatic quantum field theory , if it is really a mathematical one, will still need postulates to connect to measurements to become a physical theory.

Comment: None of those theories talk about particles. They define states and a dynamics for them. The connection to particles is only being made in your mind, and that is unnecessary, even in classical mechanics. We had this discussion before. What your detectors measure are classical particle paths because you are doing weak measurements. This has all been understood perfectly well since Mott's 1929 paper on alpha particle tracks and it has been formalized in quantum measurement theory using decoherence since the 1970s or so.

Comment: @CuriousOne give me a link to an experimental prediction of a crossection, for example, e+e- scattering. All the rest are mathamatics, quite useful but not reality. Reality is the measurements.

Comment: A cross section is the prediction or measurement of an experimental probability, it doesn't make quanta into particles. You have never in your life measured a single particle, you have only measured quanta, you are simply not willing to reflect on what that chain of high voltage gas discharges or scintillators or semiconductor detectors and electronics that you call a detector actually does at the physical level. Mott did that for you in "The wave mechanics of α-ray tracks". Please do yourself a favor and read the paper.

Comment: @CuriousOne in my view, quanta of QFT, analogous to virtual particles, are a mathematical tool to arrive at predictions for measurements. There have to be postulates that give a one to one correspondence of QFT mathematical output, to measurements. To insist that reality is quanta , and not described by quanta, is a metaphysical belief.  Reality can be described by many mathematical models, sometimes more accurately in numbers and sometimes not so much, and there exist equivalence between frameworks of tools . In the framework of first quantization and potentials, particles exist.

Comment: I think we dont know what is electron indeed but I see some physicists are wonder for example by wave-particle duality. We think intuitively, it is okay but I was wonder because we cannot define electron. We talk about somethings that are ambiguous. Anyways, thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: Quanta in QFT are exactly the same as in classical electrodynamics, they are what you see in measurements. You can only measure an atomic transition in multiples of photons because the electromagnetic field can only change in multiples of photons. Whether they are real or virtual doesn't change anything about their values. One is one. Virtual photons are, and there you are right, just a calculation tool. Quanta are not. They are the very thing that you keep mistaking for particles. Particles only "show up" when you have a high momentum state, but not every state has high p.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am curious how you fit the amplituhedron  in your physics world view. Possibly strings also are a bad fit. Back in in 1961 I was taught a creation and annihilation theory for nuclear physics states, i.e. the ground state on which the operators operated was the ground nuclear state. That is why I cannot take seriously a metaphysical frame like " quantum fields cover all space "

Comment: I haven't looked into the amplituhedron, yet, as it's not a general recipe, yet. It only seems to work in some toy models, but I would not be surprised if we had done QFT all wrong all this time. If this leads to a new interpretation, that's fine with me. It won't ruin my day, either, since it won't get us back to particles. That quantum fields cover all of space is trivial. If you assume otherwise you get false results and it won't even be consistent with thermodynamics and conservation laws. You can't just cut a hole into space without changing stuff.

Comment: If you are interested, we can move this into a chat. I would have one point to make which is about the science history of quantum mechanics which, to me, seems to explain why some people are so locked onto the particle picture that they can't imagine that it's nothing but a fluke of history, but it's better made in chat.

Comment: @CuriousOne I do not think you can change my mind, nor do I believe I can change yours. You can keep thinking of me as on old guard deluded into the particle picture and I can keep thinking of you as somebody platonically  locked into a mathematical world view.

Comment: I am not trying to change your mind. I simply want to tell you a little story that I believe is a good example for intellectual biases. What you do with it is up to you. Chat? Give me a few minutes of your time and I promise I won't try to strong arm the argument with it. I just think it's cute and it deserves some consideration in general.

Comment: @CuriousOne  OK chat, I was answering a question. how does one do the transfer if there is no suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33667/discussion-between-anna-v-and-curiousone).

Comment: @annav how is it possible to have a conversation about particles with someone who doesn’t believe in photons?

Comment: @BillAlsept  if you go to the chat , linked in the chat I made, you will see we had a friendly discussion . CuriousOne disappeared from the scene since August 2016. I suppose in this impersonal medium we discuss our physics povs , when something happens to us, we just disappear.

Comment: @annav Yes I wasn’t questioning that you couldn’t have a nice conversation with him. That’s great, I was just wondering how you do it when he can’t visualize a photon as some kind of a particle. His biggest argument against photons was that they are not solid little balls, which no one ever ever said they were.

Answer (score 3):

Today, nobody really knows what essentially an Electron is.  Nobody knows what it is really made of.  We know some of its properties which we can use to manipulate it and exploit it for our needs.  Today, the best we can say concisely about the Electron is that it’s a statistical cloud of an unknown substance.  If you want to go deeper, please read below.

In the era of Classical Physics (before the discovery of the wave-particle duality of matter’s basic constituents), the Electron was considered to be one of the fundamental and indivisible constituents of the matter.  Also then, nobody could say what it is really made of.  But the scientists could at least relax in the notion that we can define with infinite precision the Electron as a rigid sphere of mass which obeys consistently and with infinite precision all the well-known precise laws of the Classical Physics.  But the discovery of the wave-particle duality of Electron, followed by the duality’s mathematical framework known as the Quantum Mechanics, proved that the above notion is just an idealized concept based only upon our macroscopic experience of the reality.  Since the 1930s, the Electron and other fundamental particles are considered equally as both waves and particles.  They reveal either one of those aspects to us depending upon the way we trace or measure them.  There is no objective precedence to either one of the above aspects (wave or particle).  The chances to find an Electron in a certain location are only statistical and cannot be calculated precisely with the Classical Physics laws.

However, later theories try to give more specific answers to the wave-particle duality.  There’s the Bohmian theory by David Bohm which takes the electron authentically as a real classic particle which is just accompanied and influenced by some abstract waveform.  This view could be supported by the relatively recent experimental, but accidental, discovery by Yves Couder and colleagues made by using simple oil droplets.  A very good review of this experiment and its possible meanings is found here:

https://www.quantamagazine.org/20140624-fluid-tests-hint-at-concrete-quantum-reality/

Another promising theory is the Transactional Interpretation (TI) of Quantum Mechanics as first proposed by John G. Cramer in 1986.  It was recently expanded more by Ruth E. Kastner who has published a whole book about it in 2012.  A good review about this book is found here:

http://ieet.org/index.php/IEET/more/scaruffi20150108

In contrast to the above Bohmian Theory, The TI theory at its bottom line says that the authentic nature of Electron and other quantas is the waveform.  Furthermore, all the quantas, including the Electron, in their original waveforms, exist outside of our known space-time.  She calls that reality ‘Unactualized Physical Reality’.  She argues that the particles as we know them are the actualized forms of those quantas which transact with each other in the Unactualized Reality and these transactions give rise to the materialistic reality as we see it.  She continues and argues that the whole actualized reality of matter and space-time as we experience it, continues to exist, because those transactions between the actualized-quantas (particles) keep happening ceaselessly in our space-time.

The origins of the TI theory are in some abnormal solutions of the Maxwell Equations of electromagnetism.

Answer (score -1):

There was a lot of temptation and attempts to present the electron as a wave or as a wave packet. But the problem arose, because such waves and wave packets are quickly destroyed because of dispersion.
But there is a case where the dispersion disappears. This is the case when the group velocity of wave propagation becomes equal to the phase velocity.
However, the equations of quantum mechanics that existed up to now did not allow one to obtain such a wave without dispersion. Because the resulting dispersion relations did not have a point of intersection of the phase and group velocities.
Pay attention to the interesting work where this problem is solved.
http://vixra.org/abs/1710.0239